# type mismatch; found : Unit required: Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]]

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

Why the following code has a compilation error at return statement,

```
  def getData(queries: Array[String]): Dataset[Row] = {
    val res = spark.read.format("jdbc").jdbc(jdbcUrl, "", props).registerTempTable("")
    return res
  }
```

Error,

```
type mismatch; found : Unit required: Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]]
```

Scala version **2.11.11**

Spark version **2.0.0**

**EDIT:**
Actual case

```
  def getDataFrames(queries: Array[String]) = {
    val jdbcResult = queries.map(query => {
      val tablename = extractTableName(query)
      if (tablename.contains("1")) {
        spark.sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").jdbc(jdbcUrl1, query, props)
      } else {
        spark.sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").jdbc(jdbcUrl2, query, props)
      }
    })
  }
```

Here I want to return the combined output from the iteration like an Array[Dataset[Row]] or Array[DataFrame] (but Dataframe is not available in 2.0.0 as a dependency). Do the above code does the magic ? or How can I do it?

Comment: `registerTempTable` returns `Unit` you better remove the  `registerTempTable` and return Dataframe, And why are you trying to return `Array[Dataset[Row]]` ?

Comment: I have multiple queries , I want to create an array of dataframes. But in the question there was an error edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can return a `list` of `dataframes` as `List[Dataframe]`

```
def getData(queries: Array[String]): List[Dataframe] = {
  val res = spark.read.format("jdbc").jdbc(jdbcUrl, "", props)
  //create multiple dataframe from your queries
  val df1 = ???
  val df2 = ???
  val list = List(df1, df2)
  //You can create a list dynamically with list of quries 
  list
}
```

`registerTempTable` returns `Unit` you better remove the `registerTempTable` and return `Dataframe`, and return a `list` of dataframes.

**UPDATE:**

Here is how you can return list of dataframes with list of queries

```
def getDataFrames(queries: Array[String]): Array[DataFrame] = {
  val jdbcResult = queries.map(query => {
    val tablename = extractTableName(query)
    val dataframe = if (tablename.contains("1")) {
      spark.sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").jdbc("", query, prop)
    } else {
      spark.sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").jdbc("", query, prop)
    }
    dataframe
  })
  jdbcResult
}
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: pls find the edits for more details on my requirement.

Comment: @Krishas can you check the updated answer if this works ?

Comment: this removes the compilation error. Thank you. Also for spark 2, we can replace Array[DataFrame] with Array[Dataset[Row]]

Comment: @Krishas Yeah they both are the same

Answer (score 1):

Its clear from the error message that there is a type mismatch in your function.
`registerTempTable()` api creates an in-memory table scoped to the current session and stays accesible till the SparkSession is active.

[Check the return type of registerTempTable() api here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset)

change your code to the following to remove the error message:

```
def getData(queries: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val res = spark.read.format("jdbc").jdbc(jdbcUrl, "", props).registerTempTable("")

  }
```

an even better way would be to write the code as follows:

`val tempName: String = "Name_Of_Temp_View"
spark.read.format("jdbc").jdbc(jdbcUrl, "", props).createOrReplaceTempView(tempName)`

**Use the** `createOrReplaceTempView()` **as** `registerTempTable()` **is deprecated since Spark 2.0.0**

The Alternate solution as per your requirement:

`def getData(queries: Array[String], spark: SparkSession): Array[DataFrame] = { 
spark.read.format("jdbc").jdbc(jdbcUrl, "", props).createOrReplaceTempView("Name_Of_Temp_Table") 
val result: Array[DataFrame] = queries.map(query => spark.sql(query)) 
result }`

Comment: Krishas you can provide feedback or accept the answer

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I'm very much new in scala. Actually I have 2 types of SQL (in an array of sqls) int the getData method so that I have to call spark.read in if and else, so how can I combine the result and return and an array of dataframes

Comment: Shakar's answer is correct, as shown below. Next time could you share the actual function so that someone answering the question has a better understanding of your probelms

Comment: sure, sorry for the confusion.